# method readUnsignedByte in PHP

Tags: php, byte, unsigned

how get UnsignedBytes in php? In java very easy: readUnsignedByte (Java)

Answer (score 1):

There's no byte datatype in php, however, php character type is 8-bit, that is, you can use char/string type to store bytes. [fgetc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetc.php) reads a character from input and [ord](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) returns a numeric byte value, given a character.

Answer (score 0):

Php does not have a byte type. Maybe an alternative is to create a byte array to represent your byte value.